# Is it possible to combine a slice with a regular expression in a search pattern using re.search?

Tags: python

e[1] is equal to 192.168.1.1.  I would like to add regular expression to this search to prevent a match against 192.168.11.  Can anyone help?  I have beat my head against this for a while. I get a syntax error if I try to append anything after the slice.

> > > re.search(e[1], '192.168.1.11')

<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x1004c2648>

Comment: Are you sure you don't have them backwards?

Comment: Im not quite sure I do understand your question. But are you aware that '.' (dot) is a _match any character_ character? That said for example `re.search('1.2.3.4', '1a293.4')` would match. If you would like to match only '.' you could use `\.` in your pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Since e[1] is a string you can add to it with the '+' operator. For example, you can add `r'\b'`  to set a [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (note the raw string; without the 'r' prefix '\b' is a backspace):

```
>>> e = ['', '192.168.1.1']
>>> pattern = r'\b' + re.escape(e[1]) + r'\b'  #remember to escape e[1]

>>> re.search(pattern, '192.168.1.11')
>>> re.search(pattern, '192.168.1.1spam')

>>> re.search(pattern, '192.168.1.1').group()
'192.168.1.1'

>>> re.search(pattern, 'spam 192.168.1.1 eggs').group()
'192.168.1.1'

>>> string = '192.168.1.1,192.168.1.11,192.168.1.1'
>>> [x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, string)]
['192.168.1.1', '192.168.1.1']
```